# Decode the return value from a smart contract with web3.py?

Tags: python, hex, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm reposting the question since it wasn't well describe.

I'm working on a smart contract that is suppose to return 1 when I call it with a python script using web3.py, but instead of having a 1 in my python scirpt I receive an hexbytes object. I suppose I need to decode it using the ABI and web3.py but I don't know how?

I have a function like this in solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract test {
    function test(int a) public returns (int) {
            if(a > 0){
                return 1;
            }
        }
}
```

When I called it with my python script:

```
import json

import web3
from web3 import Web3

#To connect to ganache blockchain:
ganache_url = "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url))

#this script will be the account number 1 on ganache blockchain:
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[1]

#smart contract: abi, address and bytecode
abi = json.loads('....')
address = web3.toChecksumAddress("0x4A4AaA64857aa08a709A3470A016a516d3da40bf")
bytecode = "..."

#refering to the deploy coontract
contract = web3.eth.contract(address = address, abi = abi, bytecode = bytecode)

con = contract.functions.test(52).transact()
print(con.hex())
```

I have result like this:

```
<class 'hexbytes.main.HexBytes'>
0x3791e76f3c1244722e60f72ac062765fca0c00c25ac8d5fcb22c5a9637c3706d
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

The `transact()` method submits the transaction and returns transaction hash. You should first wait for the transaction to be mined, and get the transaction receipt using `w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt`. If you intend to use a transaction instead of a call you can get the result of your function by mutating the state and then reading the resulting state by calling a `view` function or mutating the state and generating an `event`.

In your case you don't mutate the state so you can mark your function as `view`:

```
function test(int a) view public returns (int)
```

and then use `call` instead of generating a transaction:

```py
contract.functions.test(52).call()
```

You can read [here about the difference between a transaction and a call](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/770).

Also the [official web3py documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html) has many examples of invoking smart contract functions.

Comment: That is not the answer for the question