# yte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, web3py

I'm experiencing some issues with web3 in Python.
The line : if tx['from'] not in ws['A']:
in this code:

```
for tx in transactions:
    if tx['from'] not in ws['A']:
        contract = w3.eth.contract(address=tx['to'], abi=CONTRACT_ABI)
        contract.functions.yourFunction().transact()

        ws.append([tx['from']])
```

returns this error : byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Now I know that the "from" variable is the issue, it needs an index number, 0, 1, 2 etc.
But my issues is how could I make sure that tx accesses the index number for the 'from' variable?

Sorry if the question is too vague, I'm a beginner in Python and I don't know exactly what to ask, thanks for reading.

Tried getting the value 'from' in tx in order to save it in an excel file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode the return value from a smart contract with web3.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716597/decode-the-return-value-from-a-smart-contract-with-web3-py)

Comment: It does not, it's not even remotely the same sadly.